# Retaining the radio button even after the submit button is clicked

Tags: javascript, html

I have 2 radio buttons 1.)Visit log and 2.)Case history. And a submit button "GET Report".

When I click on Case history I get 2 other sub radio buttons saying "incident" and "sources", My problem is after making selection among these sub radio buttons and clicking on submit, the sub radio buttons vanish.

I need the radio sub radio buttons to stay even after clicking on submit.

This is my code:

```
<head>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        function show() { document.getElementById('area').style.display = 'block'; }
        function hide() { document.getElementById('area').style.display = 'none'; }

      </script>
    </head>
    <body>        
      <form name="radios" method="GET">
        <INPUT TYPE=RADIO NAME="X" VALUE="visitlog" onclick="hide();"/>Visit Log
        <INPUT TYPE=RADIO NAME="X" VALUE="Case" onclick="show();"/>Case History
        <div id="area" style="display: none;">
        <INPUT TYPE=RADIO NAME="Y"   VALUE="incident" />Incident
        <INPUT TYPE=RADIO NAME="Y"  VALUE="Source"   />Sources
        </div>
       <input type="submit" name="GETREPORT" value="Get Report" />
      </form>
    </body>
```

How can I Retain my 2 sub radio buttons with selected radio option even after the submit button? plz help

Comment: What happens when you submit the form? The whole page may be getting refreshed, causing you to lose any DOM changes.

Comment: When I select case history->incident->get report   the sub buttons will hide, I want the sub radio buttons to remain even after the submit button is hit

Comment: Yes, but what actually happens when the form is submitted? Presumably you're doing some processing on the server side to generate the report?

Comment: Yes If CASE HISTORY is clicked: Followed BY  incident is selected incident table from database is getting printed, if its source radio button selected then source table from database is printed.

Comment: Normally you'd need to do some kind of check on the server-side and either render alternative markup as [Max has suggested](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28828325/1794631). Alternatively, you could provide some flag (querystring, hidden element, etc). that you can use in your javascript to set the DOM to the correct state.

Comment: you want to Post the form asynchoronous.Use jquery form submit plugin.

Comment: @Innovation sorry I dint get u

Comment: I want to say.Do not submit form.Use ajax call.

Comment: PPL who vote down, Kindly correct my mistakes and specify the reason for your  vote down. What is the use of simply proving your vote power on others blindly

Comment: do you mind using using `localstorage` and simplified with `jQuery`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just check on your page if the submit button was clicked and then **echo style ="display:block"**. Otherwise you **echo style="display:none"**.

Of course your javascript disappears after reloading the page.

```
   <body>        
  <form name="radios" method="POST">
    <INPUT <?php if (isset($_POST["X"]) && $_POST["X"] == "visitlog") echo "checked ";?> TYPE=RADIO NAME="X" VALUE="visitlog" onclick="hide();"/>Visit Log
    <INPUT <?php if (isset($_POST["X"]) && $_POST["X"] == "Case") echo "checked ";?>TYPE=RADIO NAME="X" VALUE="Case" onclick="show();"/>Case History
    <?php if (isset($_POST["submit"])) echo "<div id=\"area\" style=\"display:block\">"; else echo "<div id=\"area\" style=\"display:none\">"; ?> 
    <INPUT TYPE=RADIO NAME="Y"   VALUE="incident" />Incident
    <INPUT TYPE=RADIO NAME="Y"  VALUE="Source"   />Sources
    </div>
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Get Report" />
  </form>
</body>
```

Comment: I used ur code, but the sub buttons are getting printed before i click on case radio button

Comment: Look at your HTML Code, what is the output? btw: in my post I said display:hidden, but it has to be display:none

Comment: Now the sub radio buttons are appearing even after I select vist log->submit :(

Comment: look at your console, do you have errors? validate your html and look if there are errors.

Comment: No errors.Ur code is working fine :) But the thing is I want to set the checked  radio button to retain after the submit. How can I do that?

Comment: i have tried with your solution it's not working.same issue ,radio buttons are not retain after submit ,it will refresh.

Comment: and what is shown in the html code? Is the "checked" displayed? Maybe try checked="checked", it's difficult to give an answer, if I cant see the code

Comment: "checked" is not displayed, and tried with  checked="checked", again same problem.

Comment: ok, I forgot some Parentheses, now it should work, but you should see that there are Parentheses missing

Comment: no ,it's not about the brackets, i have tried with putting all brackets everything  properly , at the beginning only when your first time edited .i am not getting why it's not checking if(isset()) condition and refreshing

Comment: method="GET" did you use GET or POST?

Comment: OP is using `method="GET"` and you're reading `$_POST`... try with get or `$_REQUEST` (for both...)

Comment: I used GET  , Sorry for the late reply.

Answer (score 1):

You need to `READ` the form values sent with `$_GET` method in `PHP`.

### PHP <sup>(at the top of your php file)</sup>

```
<?php

// default values
$area_display     = "none";
$checked_visitlog = "";
$checked_case     = "";
$checked_incident = "";
$checked_source   = "";

// only if $_GET is not empty
if ( !empty($_GET) ) {
    // "x" value
    switch ( $_GET["X"] ) {
        case "visitlog":
            $checked_visitlog = "checked";
            break;
        case "Case":
            $area_display = "block";
            $checked_case = "checked";
            break;
    }
    //"y" value
    switch ( $_GET["Y"] ) {
        case "incident":
            $checked_incident = "checked";
            break;
        case "Source":
            $checked_source = "checked";
            break;
    }
}

?>
```

Then, when you set up the `HTML` *write* those values and add the property.

### HTML

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function show() {
        document.getElementById('area').style.display = 'block';
    }

    function hide() {
        document.getElementById('area').style.display = 'none';
    }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <form name="radios" method="GET">
        <input <?php echo $checked_visitlog;?> type="radio" name="X" value="visitlog" onclick="hide();" />Visit Log
        <input <?php echo $checked_case;?> type="radio" name="X" value="Case" onclick="show();" />Case History
        <div id="area" style="display: <?php echo $area_display;?>;">
            <input <?php echo $checked_incident;?> type="radio" name="Y" value="incident" />Incident
            <input <?php echo $checked_source;?> type="radio" name="Y" value="Source" />Sources
        </div>
        <input type="submit" name="GETREPORT" value="Get Report" />
    </form>
</body>
</head>
```

Comment: Its not working :(  On clicking case ->sub radio buttons-> submit everything goes off...